# howto make locally terminated tcp connections go through prerouting and postrouting?

Tags: linux, testing, networking, tcp, netfilter

I am developing an application that filters and mangles packets using netfilter queue's. It's rather complicated and needs to perform well so I would like to automate some rigorous testing. To do this I need to be to be able to route some TCP connections through my system, however, I don't want to have to rely on two other machines to act as client and server. I would prefer to run a local client that sends data and a local server that checks the mangled result.

The problem is that my application needs to intercept packets at the PREROUTING stage and so packets generated by the local client can't just be routed to the loopback interface.

So I need some way to inject packets before the prerouting stage and intercept them back after postrouting. If I could somehow use stream sockets to send and receive the data that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward way I can think of doing this is to use a [tun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TUN/TAP) device. The tun device allows you to inject packets from userspace that appear to arrive through the tun interface. You could either write code to create and manipulate the tun interface yourself, or you can make use of an application like [OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net/) that already does this. With OpenVPN it would be easy: no special raw sockets or anything: you just send it IP packets encapsulated in UDP and it will make them arrive through a tun interface.

Comment: The jump to prerouting still doesn't allow me to intercept the packets after postrouting so it's not good enough. The Tun device seems to be exactly what I need. Thanks!

Comment: The command is faulty, and will error out with "Invalid argument", because a base chain cannot call a base chain, for reasons (a) it's not implemented at all, (2) would lead to loops and therefore forbidden from the start.

Answer (score 0):

I've been thinking a bit about this and using the tun devices my client and server test applications should be able to use plain linux sockets. I will explain how this can work by describing the path of a packet sent by the test client.

Prerequisites:

a) Two tun devices each providing access to a distinct subnetwork

b) routing table was set up to route traffic to the correct tun device

1) the client sends a packet to an address in the tun1 subnetwork

2) the app attached to tun1 (tun1app) will translate the dst address of the packet to an address in tun2 subnetwork and the source address to an address in the tun1 subnetwork different from the address of the tun1 interface

3) tun1app will send the modified packet back out

4) after routing tun2app will receive the packet and translate the destination address to the tun2 interface and the source address to an address in the tun2 network different from the interface address

5) tun2app will send it back out and the server will receive the packet assuming the destination port is the one the server is listening on

Packets from the server will follow the inverse path.

This seems like the core idea of a very useful tool. Does anyone know of a tool that is able to do this?

Answer (score 0):

All connections from-and-to localhost itself *do* go over PREROUTING and POSTROUTING. Whoever tells something else is mistaken. (You can verify that with `ip6tables -t raw -I OUTPUT -j TRACE`, and you will see that it passes through OUTPUT-POSTROUTING-PREROUTING-INPUT when, for example, you `ping6 ::1` yourself.)

Comment: Thanks for rectifying that. I do however need to emulate a connection going from PREROUTING -> FORWARD -> POSTROUTING, i.e. I want a locally terminated connection to follow the path an externally terminated connection would. So a setup with tun interfaces still seems like the most transparent solution. Perhaps I should have choses a less presumptuous title.

Comment: *veth* seems preferable to *tun* to do that.